# Do I need a transit visa in Amsterdam if I'm on advance parole?

Tags: visas, amsterdam

I am returning to the US via Amsterdam. I have a US advance parole document. Do I need a transit visa to transit through Amsterdam? Their website mentions US resident permits but does not talk about advance parole.

Comment: Most nationalities do not require a transit visa in the Netherlands. Should we assume that your does?

Comment: Not sure I understand the question correctly: Do you have a passport? To flight to US you need correct immigration documents (which are also pre-checked during or before you start travel), maybe you were looking such requirements?

Comment: sry, perhaps I did not explain completely. I hold an Indian passport. For travel from US to India via Amsterdam - no problem. For return from India to US via Amsterdam, since I don't have a green card but have advance parole document I-512, I was wondering if I can transit without a visa. The rules are different even within EU states, for example, Germany does not allow transit on I-512 without a Schengen visa. Netherlands used to allow, I just want to make sure they still do but I cannot find any information.

Comment: There's nothing special about this situation with respect to the Schengen area; you can transit without a visa like mostly everyone else.